# Recursively printing out the sections and subsections of an outline

Tags: c, recursion, printf

Recursion is the one thing I have loads of trouble with. For this assignment we are supposed to print out an outline of sections and sub-sections. Take the following as an example.

```
Section 1 
 Section 1.A
   Section 1.A.1
   Section 1.A.2 
 Section 1.B
   Section 1.B.1
   Section 1.B.2 
Section 2
 Section 2.A 
   Section 2.A.1
   Section 2.A.2 
 Section 2.B
   Section 2.B.1 
   Section 2.B.2
```

This example has a depth of 3 and height of 2.

Here is my code thus far, which doesn't come anywhere near the correct output.

```
void printDepth(int depth, int width, int minusDepth, int minusWidth) {
    int i = 0;
    if(depth == 0)
        printf("Section XX\n");


    else {
        printf("\t");
        printDepth(depth -1, width, minusDepth, minusWidth);
    }
}
```

Here is the call from main()

```
int minusDepth = 0;
int minusWidth = 0;
printDepth(depth, width, minusDepth, minusWidth);
```

However, for a depth = 4 and width = 5 this only prints out:

\t\t\t\tSection XX

I'm really not sure how to proceed. Recursion is the bane of my existence.

Comment: need to see full code...

Comment: added the rest of it. (not the trivial parts like atoi() to get command-line arguments as ints)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a loop that prints the sections at the current depth and executes `height` (which I call `width` instead) recursions.  You also need to pass a string containing the current prefix of the section string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_DEPTH 100
#define MAX_WIDTH  99  // NOTE: if you increase this then section's decl in printDepth needs to be updated too

void printDepth_r(int currDepth, int depth, int width, char *section, char *sub)
{
  if (currDepth == depth)  // recursion base case
    return;

  for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
  {
    // TODO: write to sub the subsection determined by (currDepth, width)

    fprintf(stdout, "%*sSection %s\n", currDepth * 2, "", section);

    // TODO: append "." to sub for descendant recursions

    printDepth_r(currDepth + 1, depth, width, section, sub + /* TODO: num chars written to sub */);
  }
}

int printDepth(int depth, int width)
{
  char section[MAX_DEPTH * (2 + 1) + 1];  // NOTE: 2 == 1 + (int) (log(99) / log(10));

  assert(sizeof(section) >= MAX_DEPTH * (1 + (int) (log(MAX_WIDTH) / log(10)) + 1) + 1);

  if (depth > MAX_DEPTH || width > MAX_WIDTH)
    return -1;

  printDepth_r(0, depth, width, section, section);

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printDepth(3, 2);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that we pass the same values of `depth`, `width` and `section` to all of our recursions.  So, if we wanted to reduce the amount of stack space the recursion eats at every level, then we could pull these out into a structure and pass 1 struct pointer to these 3 constants instead.  Or, even better, we could store these values in thread local storage.  Either way would allow deeper recursions before overflowing your stack.

Comment: I really appreciate these in depth answers, but if you could remove the code, or at least some portions of it, that may help keep me out of trouble. This is an assignment for a course I'm taking and I was really only looking for some hints on what to do next as opposed to the full solution.

Comment: I  was planning on writing my own code, I just needed to pointers, but now I'm worried that if my professor or TA were to see this I could get in trouble.

Comment: The assignment tells use we can put a cap on depth at 9 and cap on width at 26

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope I don't sound ungrateful when I asked that favor, I just want to make sure I can complete it on my own.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printDepth(int deep, int depth, int height, char *table) {
    if(deep == depth)
        return ;

    int i, j;
    char bak = table[deep];
    for(i = 0; i < height; ++i){
        printf("%*s%s", deep*2, "", "Section ");
        for(j = 0; j <= deep; ++j){
            if(j)
                putchar('.');
            putchar(table[j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
        printDepth(deep+1, depth, height, table);
        table[deep]++;
    }
    table[deep] = bak;//restore
}

int main(void){
    char table[] = "1A1";//Effective range up to 1-9 and A-Z
    printDepth(0, 3, 2, table);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate these in depth answers, but if you could remove the code, or at least some portions of it, that may help keep me out of trouble. This is an assignment for a course I'm taking and I was really only looking for some hints on what to do next as opposed to the full solution.

Comment: What are you talking about **remove the code, or at least some portions of it, that may help keep me out of trouble**?? Are you saying you are not scholastically honest enough to use the examples as guidance without block copy/pasting it as your own answer?? This is a stunningly troubling request.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Most cheaters just delete the whole question and all the answers.

Comment: I wasn't planning on using the code, which is why I got worried. When I asked my question I was hoping for a hint, a tip as to where to go next, not two complete answers. I appreciate that y'all put some much effort in it, but if a professor were to see this, even though I'm not using the code, I would get in trouble for having solicited unoriginal code, when in reality all I wanted was someone to give me a tip.